# Magento - 2 questions about breadcrumbs

Tags: magento, breadcrumbs

I have 2 question about Magento breadcrumbs.

1) How to remove slash from breacrumbs? Now looks: Home / Page, but i want only Home Page (without slash)

2) How insert the breadcrumbs to extension page? I try to insert breadcrumbs into xml file of page and into phtml page but doesnt work.

Can some help me?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To remove slashes edit the page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml template (somewhere near the 40th line)
2. Better explanation is an example. In default Magento installation breadcrumbs are places in two steps:
     a) block added to the layout in the page.xml layout file
     b) block is rendered on a page in template (page/1column.phtml, page/3columns.phtml etc.)

Comment: 1) Thanks, I'm blind
2) Yes, I have code for breadcrumbs in xml and in phtml files too, but breadcrumbs not displayed